# How to get one MAX() between SUMs of several columns in SQL?

Tags: sum, max

I need to select `MAX()` between `SUM(Math)`, `SUM(English)`, `SUM(Physics)`

[image: table]

Result must be:

```
19 | English
```

Comment: What are you going to do if the person has two values that are maximum?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It's never going to be pretty, but heres one attempt:

```
select gt, case gt when math then 'Math' 
                   when physics then 'Physics' 
                   when english then 'English' 
           end 
from (
    select greatest(math, physics, english) as gt
         , math, english, physics 
    from (
        select sum(math) as math
             , sum(english) as english
             , sum(physics) as physics 
        from scores
    )
)
```

Comment: I like this better than the `UNPIVOT` solution because it is not version dependent.  Hopefully everyone is upgraded past 2005, but if you are still stuck in 2000 land...

Comment: @SteveMangiameli: I don't see how this is better than UNPIVOT. While UNPIVOT is not supported in 2000 or lower versions, GREATEST isn't supported in *any* version (if we are speaking about SQL Server).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server, this is a good scenario to use `UNPIVOT`.  You can use write a `SELECT` to give you the single-row result of `SUM` values, then apply `UNPIVOT` to essentially convert that row into a column... and from there you just `SELECT TOP 1...`

Here's an example that gives you the exact results you're looking for:

```
create table #Scores
(
      name    nvarchar(255)
    , Math    int
    , English int
    , Physics int
)

insert #Scores (name, Math, English, Physics)
values 
      ('Pete',4,5,3)
    , ('Mark',5,5,4)
    , ('David',4,5,3)
    , ('Lisa',3,4,4);


SELECT TOP 1 sup.SubjectName, sup.Score
FROM 
    (SELECT  SUM(Math) AS Math, 
             SUM(English) AS English, 
             SUM(Physics) AS Physics 
     FROM #Scores) s
UNPIVOT
    (Score FOR SubjectName IN (Math, English, Physics)) sup
ORDER BY sup.Score DESC
```

A few other answers "manually unpivot" the results by performing a `UNION ALL` for individual `SELECT...SUM()` statements. However, in that scenario, you would see one table scan for each `SELECT...SUM()` (ie, one per column that you manually unpivot).

From a performance perspective, using the `UNPIVOT` syntax will scale much better than the `UNION ALL` approach. The `UNION ALL` approach will access the table once for each statement (in this case, three times). By getting the three `SUM` values in a single `SELECT`, SQL Server will perform a single table scan to get the three `SUM` values, then the `UNPIVOT` and `SELECT TOP 1` is a comparatively minor CPU operation.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly pretty

```
select top (1)WITH TIES tt.* 
from ( select 'math'    as [subject], sum(math)    as [sum] from table 
       union all
       select 'english' as [subject], sum(english) as [sum] from table 
       union all
       select 'Physics' as [subject], sum(Physics) as [sum] from table 
     ) tt
order by tt.sum desc
```

Victim of data design
If you had a table
userID
subjectID
score
then it would be a be cleaner (IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

This works in DB2:

```
select  max(sum(cola), sum(colb))
from    table
```

As people don't think this works, here is an example you can run on your own db2 instance:

```
select max(sum(col1),sum(col2)) 
from (values(1,2),(4,3),(5,6)) as temp (col1,col2)
```

returns `11`.

Besides an aggregate, `MAX()` is a scalar function in DB2, equivalent of the standard `GREATEST()`. See [DB2 docs, scalar `MAX()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_maxscalar.dita?lang=en).

Comment: This is will show the topmost total but won't show which subject(s) scored it.

Comment: @AndriyM, I agree, this does not return the subject as well as the max.

Answer (score 0):

Even less pretty

```
CREATE TABLE Scores
(
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Math INT,
    English INT,
    Physics INT
);

INSERT Scores
VALUES  ('Pete',4,5,4),
        ('Mark',5,5,4),
        ('David',4,5,3),
        ('Lisa',3,4,4);

;WITH cte
AS
(
  SELECT SUM(Math) AS Math,
         SUM(ENGLISH) AS English,
         SUM(Physics) AS Physics
  FROM Scores
)

SELECT CASE
         WHEN Math > English AND Math > Physics THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), Math) + ' | Math'
         WHEN English > Math AND English > Physics THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), English) + ' | English'
         WHEN Physics > English AND Physics > Math THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), Physics) + ' | Physics'
         ELSE 'Error'
       END AS HighestResult
FROM cte;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76a75/5/0).